# Foundation 6, plugin destroy

Tags: tooltip, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using tooltips to display form errors. What I'm trying to do is to display tooltips on some inputs, validated from an ajax call.

On each submission i want to remove these tooltips, check validations, and display new set of tooltips if needed. So I'm using the foundation('destroy') method on each inputs that have .has-tip class.

```
function displayTip(elt, msg){
    var options = {
        tipText: msg,
        templateClasses: 'tooltip--error',
    }
    elt.addClass('has-tip'); // <= using JQuery 'cause triggerClass option seems not working...
    var tip = new Foundation.Tooltip(elt, options);
}

function hideTips(){       
    $('.has-tip').each(function(index){
        $(this).removeClass('has-tip');
        try {
            $(this).foundation('destroy');
        } catch(e) {
            //console.info();
        }
    });
}
```

Unfortunately that doesn't work and I have these console errors:

```
foundation.js:8598 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hoverDelay' of null
foundation.js:8558 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of null
```

Please help ! :-)